# JavaScript Firestore get Added Document ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I get the created firestore document id?

What I have tried with no success:
const db = firebase.firestore();

```
db.collection("my_collection").doc().set({
   data: data
})
.then(docRef => {
    console.log(docRef);
})
.catch((error) => {
    // catch error
});
```

This always gives me undefined with the `docRef`

I have also tried the following `.then` options: `.then(function(docRef) { ... }` and `.then((docRef) => { ... }`

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.